# Pass dynamic module into another module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I don't know how to phrase this or even how to start, I'm trying to figure out how to use the dynamic module:

```
import('./icons/checkmark').then((module) => { return module.default() })
```

and pass that module into another module:

```
render() {
   return <Valid icon={<Checkmark />} />
}
```

for the life of me, I don't even know where to begin searching.

Comment: check this https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import

Comment: Best solution for code splitting is to use react-loadable: https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable